# Python: using an if statement on an argument which may or may not be there

Tags: python, if-statement, argv

I've been trying to make a small script (I'm brand new to Python, by the way), which will return a a scrabble score for a given word (argv[1], and to prompt me to type a word if I dont give it one. After fiddling around with if statements and many index errors later, I settled on this:

```
try:
    do something with sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'Type an argument'
```

But it's not as elegant as I would like. Its basically just saying "If you get this kind of error, print this:" right? I had been trying something like:

```
if argv[1] >= 1:
    do something with sys.argv[1]
else:
    print 'Type an argument'
```

But I kept getting an index error on the if portion, which i think i figured out was because if argv[1] is less than one, there is no argument, which means `argv[1]` doesn't exist. am i on the right page? I'd like to say something like "if there's no argument given, print this:" Is that possible?

Here's the actual code I'm using

```
from sys import argv
from string import maketrans

i = 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J' 'K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P' 'Q' 'R' 'S' 'T' 'U' 'V' 'W' 'X' 'Y' 'Z'
o = '0' '2' '2' '1' '0' '3' '1' '3' '0' '7' '4' '0' '2' '0' '0' '2' '9' '0' '0' '0' '0' '3' '3' '7' '3' '9' '0' '2' '2' '1' '0' '3' '1' '3' '0' '7' '4' '0' '2' '0' '0' '2' '9' '0' '0' '0' '0' '3' '3' '7' '3' '9'
t = maketrans(i, o)

def main():
  try:
   print sum(int(x) for x in argv[1].translate(t)) + len(argv[1])
  except IndexError:
   print 'Type a word, you shmuck'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: It's very odd to write strings like that: you aren't making a list; Python is simply concatenating consecutive string literals. It's the same as `i = 'abcdefg...xyz'`. For that matter, just use `from string import ascii_letters` and use that rather than `i`.

Comment: Check out [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), if you're on Python 2.7 or 3.x.

Comment: It was a holdover from when I was playing with the maketrans function. It didn't want to translate a single character letter to a two digit number (z and q are worth ten points). I thought separating them might help. It didn't but I forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of Python's philosophy is "It is better to ask forgiveness than permission" - and as this is an error case, there is no harm to the `try`, `except`.  That said, if you want to avoid it, you could just check the number of arguments:

```
def main():
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print "We need at least one argument"
        return
    # Remainder of implementation goes here
```

Comment: So if i put 'len(argv)' instead of 'len(argv[x])', it specifies the amount of arguments as opposed to the length of the string used as an argument?

Comment: ok so I just tried your implementation and i still get the same index error.

if len(argv) < 1:
   print 'Type a word, you shmuck'
  else:
   if argv[1] == '-w':
    print sum(int(x) for x in argv[2].translate(w)) + len(argv[2])
   else:
    print sum(int(x) for x in argv[1].translate(s)) + len(argv[1])

Comment: @DanielForsyth - you need to make sure that `len(argv) < 2` rather than `< 1` since there will always be one argument (the name of the script that was invoked).

Comment: that worked! thanks so much. It confused me that they started at argv[0] - it made me think that argv[0] didn't count as an argv.